# Spark Structured Streaming v2.4.0 - checkpoint directory growing forever: *.tmp.crc files are never deleted

Tags: apache-spark

I run `Spark (2.4)` structured streaming job that reads from `Kafka topic` and writes back aggregated data to different topic using window with watermark. In such configuration Spark requires checkpoint directory. Problem is that size of checkpoint directory grows forever due to `*.crc.tmp` files are never deleted. These files are present in commits, offsets and state subdirectories.
I use option `spark.sql.streaming.minBatchesToRetain` in order to limit how much history will be kept, but hidden temporary `crc` files seem to remain on file system forever.

Example, let's see regular files in commits subdirectory:

```
ls checkpoint/commits/     
6605  6606  6607  6608  6609  6610  6611  6612  6613  6614
```

Now, let's include hidden files

```
$ls -a checkpoint/commits/ | head
.
..
..0.085caf0c-c924-411c-8907-5b1c3856de9d.tmp.crc
..1000.6c40ff1c-2ad5-4c88-a04b-1545089904db.tmp.crc
..1001.abebcebd-2cb9-49e7-a058-79735b8f1b9d.tmp.crc
..100.1c0f0619-63a5-46e4-9122-0f2ef6317d3b.tmp.crc
..1002.880fcde1-3982-4886-aa5b-c62b7542b27f.tmp.crc
..1003.68f41a4c-096e-4449-949f-9adeb5a78673.tmp.crc
..1004.57558c08-05fe-49e0-9b0e-96d278aed5eb.tmp.crc
..1005.5f653083-7e4d-4931-9cd3-c53aa0c0d524.tmp.crc

$ls -a checkpoint/commits/ | grep -c .tmp.crc
6657
```

After only couple of hours of operation I have more than 6000 files only in commits subdirectory, while in complete checkpoint directory i have around 100K files. Job was running for several hours.

Is it a bug in Spark ? Does anyone knows how to tell Spark to automatically delete old `*.tmp.crc` files ?

Comment: It seems that issue is not linked with `kafka` source or sink, I managed to reproduce problem with minimal configuration reading/writing csv files: `SparkSession.builder().master("local[1]").appName("Test").getOrCreate().readStream().schema(new StructType().add("line", DataTypes.StringType)).format("csv").load("WORK/in").writeStream().format("csv").option("path", "WORK/out").option("checkpointLocation", "checkpoint").start().awaitTermination();`  In checkpoint/commits I still have files like `..0.43bb9f22-1278-44e8-b19b-3d7ec457e344.tmp.crc`

Comment: There is a workaround described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-28025?focusedCommentId=16862908&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel