# Spark checkpointing has a lot of tmp.crc files

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming where I read a stream from Kafka and after some transformation I write the resulted stream to Kafka.

I see a lot of hidden ..*tmp.crc files within my checkpoint directory. These files are not getting cleaned up and ever growing in number.
Am I missing some configuration?

I am not running spark on Hadoop. Using EBS based volume for checkpointing.

Comment: Similar question than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767367/spark-structured-streaming-v2-4-0-checkpoint-directory-growing-forever-tmp